# google translate library is printing <googletrans.models.Translated at 0x1eaf9bfd198> instead of text

Tags: python, translation, google-translate

I have used google translate library to convert languages and it is running properly but in output it is not showing the name of language and it showing some code .

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('안녕하세요.')

<googletrans.models.Translated at 0x1eaf9bfd198>
```

Comment: This is a default representation of an object. It will contain the result. Check the docs on how to get the desired information out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `text` property to see the translated text.

```
>>> from googletrans import Translator
>>> translator = Translator()
>>> result = translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
>>> result.text
'Hi.'
```

To see destination and source languages use the `dest` and `src` properties.

```
>>> result.src
'ko'
>>> result.dest
'en'
```

Seems like `googletrans.models.Translated` does not override the `__repr__` function and so shows the default (which displays its address in memory). The [docs](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) indicate it should show the fields, but for me it doesn't. So the docs are either too old or too new.

You can introspect the properties of the `Translated` object using `dir`, if you want to see whats available to you. Look at the properties that don't have the double underscores at each end.

```
>>> dir(result)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'dest', 'extra_data', 'origin', 'pronunciation', 'src', 'text']
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
```

By

```
translator.detect('안녕하세요.').lang
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had encountered this problem.

Just assign any variable to the function `translator.translate`, such as:

```py
k = translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
```

and print k only. This worked for me. You can also give it a try.